# Is this sentence using correct vocabulary?

Tags: grammar

I was just grateful to be surrounded by a feeling of care and familiarity.

Is this correct or should I instead write it as “I was just grateful to be surrounded with feelings of care and familiarity.” Which would be better?

Answer (score 1):

1. It's hard to be surrounded by feelings.
2. I don't think "care" is really a feeling.

Do you mean something like this?

> I was just grateful to be surrounded by familiar people who cared.

Comment: Or _an atmosphere of..._